# A reference to 'YourProject' could not be added. An assembly must have a 'dll' or 'exe' extension in order to be referenced

Tags: .net, visual-studio, system.reactive, visual-studio-2015

When I attempt to add a reference to a class library type project within the same solution, I get a message box saying:

> A reference to 'YourProject' could not be added. An assembly must have
>   a 'dll' or 'exe' extension in order to be referenced.

I am using Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 on 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium and all my projects, the one I am trying to set a reference *to* as well as the one I am trying to set a reference *from* target .NET Framework v4.

**Update**

I am adding some more context. Here is what happened.

I downloaded the source of Rx.NET and when I opened the solution file, it first warned me with a dialog box asking me if I trusted the source from which I had downloaded this solution, and if it wanted me to proceed. I clicked **Yes, go ahead** for each of the 17 projects in the solution.

[image]

Now, when I look at the project references, they are all screwed up in all of the projects. None of them have their references resolved.

When I try to manually set the reference again using the **Add Reference** dialog, and by selecting the project from the **Solution -> Projects** section, I get a dialog box with the message I mentioned earlier.

**Further Update**

It seems like the problem is the missing assemblies namely `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks`, `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`, and `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop`. I have no idea where to get them from or if they even exist anymore or if they have been merged into some other existing assembly since the the latest stable release v2.2.5 of Rx source code was shipped.

Comment: So what is the extension of `YourProject`?

Comment: No, the output it generates.

Comment: The one I am trying to set a reference *to* is a class library, as mentioned in the first line of my question. The one I am trying to set a reference *from*, though this shouldn't make much of a difference, is a console app.

Comment: Yes, and the class library... what does it output exactly?

Comment: @DavidG It is the source code library for `System.Reactive.Core`, i.e. the core of Rx.NET.

Comment: OK, I am *really* trying to help but you are not making it easy! When you build the project, what actual file is being produced on your disk? What does the build process create?

Comment: @DavidG Sorry if you were offended. I meant to answer your questions but I could only answer what I understood. It was only your last question that made it very clear to me what you were asking. Anyways, I ran the ms build batch file that came with the project and I am somewhat clued up now about what the exact problem might be. I will update the question with more information once I am finished troubleshooting the build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Too long for a comment)

The Rx code base is a funny beast. Older versions of the code base (2.2.3) were not very friendly to build locally. First I would suggest running on a recent OS (win7 is not under mainstream support anymore and you have days left before the free upgrade to Win10 expires). Then ensure you have the latest .NET SDK's installed. You may also have to be careful as to which Build target you are running. DEBUG and RELEASE from memory don't build in Rx.NET. You need to pick a target like `DEBUG40` or `RELEASE81` which will define the platform you are building for. Finally I would suggest building the Rx code base as it came, and then referencing that from your console app in another solution, again just due to the peculiar way the Rx code base has been structured (for platform support)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am scared of taking chances with my only dev machine by installing Windows 10, but I'll do that in about 2 weeks on another machine. Meanwhile, I'll try adding the Rx projects individually to a new solution that has my console app.

Comment: Thank you very much. :-) I am sure I did but I have forgotten the exact error I received at that time because I have been trying various things to get it to compile. So, I erased my local copy and got myself a new clone and tried it again. This time it reports the error "The target "Build" does not exist in the project System.Reactive.Linq" and it reports that there are 125 more errors other than this. Also, I see the same broken assembly references as depicted in the picture shown in the question.

Comment: thank you so much. After all these hours of trying, I suddenly realized that I was building from the wrong source repo. I was building from the one on codeplex when I should have known that the updated, latest repo is on github. I built from that one and had no problems. "We're now in business," I said to myself. Anyway, the thing is, though, it built using .NET 3.5, I suspect, because I saw in the output window that it kept saying Debug35. How do change all the projects to build targeting 4.5? Do I have to manually go and change all project's properties?

Comment: From command line with msbuild add the switch `/t:DEBUG45`. From VS in the toolbar, there is a dropdown. It is normally populated with `Debug` and `Release`. For this solution you will see it has lots of other options. Vhoose `Debug45`

Comment: Thanks. My question is: should I be choosing the `Debug` and `Release` values from the drop-downs in Visual Studio for each of the projects or could I do it once for the entire solution? I am not even sure if the latter is an option. Just throwing the question at you.

Comment: Once for the whole solution, but DONT use `Debug` or `Release` for the Rx code base. You need to specify the platform you are targeting, so choose the appropriate debug or release target for the platform e.g. Debug40, Debug45, Release81 etc..

Comment: Yes, thank you. I saw that when I downloaded the source. :-)

Answer (score 0):

When adding a project reference, make sure you are under the Projects > solution section of the tree on the left of the add reference dialog

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I ensured that that was the case. The error is reported inspite of that.